# Expand $\sqrt{1-x}$ up to and including the term $x^2$ (How should i proceed further)

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am trying to solve a 2 part question, the first part is to expand $\sqrt{1-x}$ up to and including the term $x^2$ which I did.

This gives me $1-(0.5)x-(0.125)x^2 + ...$

However, the 2nd part of the question says that by taking $x=(1/64)$ in the expansion of part (i) -> which refers to the one above, deduce that $\sqrt 7 = 10837/4096$. How do i do this part?

EDIT
(After Hint Given By SimpliFire):

$$ \sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\frac{\sqrt{63}}8=\frac38\sqrt7 $$
$$ =\frac83\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}\;=\sqrt7 $$
$$ =\frac83\left(1-\frac12\left(\frac1{64}\right)-\frac18\left(\frac1{64}\right)^2\right)\; $$
$$ =\frac83\left(1-\frac1{128}-\frac1{32768}\right)\; $$
$$ =\frac83\left(\frac{32768}{32768}-\frac{256}{32768}-\frac1{32768}\right)\; $$
$$ =\frac83\left(\frac{32511}{32768}\right)\; $$
$$ =\frac{260088}{98304} $$
$$ \frac{10837}{4096}\;\approx\sqrt7 $$

I'm not sure if I can present it like this, if it is okay i will post it as my answer :X

Comment: **HINT:** $$\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\frac{\sqrt{63}}8=\frac38\sqrt7$$

Comment: ah... i think i solved it, but im not sure if I presented my workings correctly. How do I post my answer here with the nice square root and fractional formattings?

Comment: You could answer your own question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial. If you want us to check your solution, then you should instead put it in the original post (above).

Comment: Thanks! I have posted my working, im not sure if the presentation is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct approach!

Some minor notational errors. Here's how I would lay it out:

---

Since

$$ \sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\frac{\sqrt{63}}8=\frac38\sqrt7 \implies\frac83\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\sqrt7,$$ from the previous part, we have the approximation 
$$\begin{align}\sqrt7\approx\frac83\left(1-\frac12\left(\frac1{64}\right)-\frac18\left(\frac1{64}\right)^2\right)&=\frac83\left(1-\frac1{128}-\frac1{32768}\right) \\&=\frac83\left(\frac{32768}{32768}-\frac{256}{32768}-\frac1{32768}\right)\\&=\frac83\left(\frac{32511}{32768}\right)=\frac{260088}{98304}=\frac{10837}{4096}\end{align}$$ as required.

Comment: Nicely put, thank you so much :D